# $(G-H) \cup \{ e \}$ subgroup if and only if $H$ improper group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ a subgroup of $G$.

Show $(G-H)\cup \{ e \}$ is subgroup of $G$ if and only if $H$ is improper subgroup of $G$.

$\text{My attempt:}$

I maked inversed, it's kinda easy. If H is improper then $H = G$ or $H = \{ e \}$ and you get always $(G − H)\cup \{ e \}$ is $G$ or $\{ e \}$ which are obvious subgroups because are improper. Inverse i have no ideea.

*I don't want a solution, i want a start point. I want to know how this problem can be solved, how to "understand" this problem, how to get an ideea from iphothesys. It's useless solution if i don't understand the problem. I only want a full proof only and only if i can't solve it. Thank you for understanding me.*

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have no clue how to start. What do you suggest, what to "observe" from problem? What ideas to get from ipothesys?

Comment: It's an if and only if statement, so you know that you have to prove both directions. Start by assuming on side of the equivalence and try to derive the other. If that doesn't work: try it the other way around.

Comment: I maked inversed, it's kinda easy. If $H$ is improper then $H = G$ or $H = \{ e \}$ and you get always $(G-H) \cup \{ e \}$ is $G$ or $\{ e \}$ which are obvious subgroups because are improper. Inverse i have no ideea.

Comment: Include this attempt in your post! :)

Comment: ok, post edited.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is pretty much the same you use to prove that transcendental numbers are not closed under sum.

Notice that if $h\in H$ you can write it as $g(g^{-1}h)$, notice now that $g^{-1}h$ cannot belong to $H$ so it must belong to $(G-H)\cup\{e\}$, like $g$, but this would imply $h\in(G-H)\cup\{e\}$ which cannot be.

Comment: How you get the ideea? I need to start learn how to "get" ideeas from problems and idk how.

Comment: well, $(G-H)\cup\{e\}$ contains the identity and is closed under inverse, so the only way to show it's not a subgroup if $H$ is different from $G$ and $\{e\}$ is to prove that there are two elements $g_1,g_2$ in $(G-H)\cup\{e\}$ such that $g_1g_2\in H$, so you consider $h\in H$, $g_1$ arbitrary, and $g_2=g^{-1}_1h$

Comment: Why? I don't see from where you get the ideea to use that. I wanted an ideea or an "obvious" thing to try myself.

Comment: ok, the idea is "If H is proper, then in what ways can $(G-H)\cup\{e\}$ fail to be a subgroup?"

Comment: I understand how you solved, but i preffered to say me how to start the solution. I don't want a solution, i want a start point, to see how i can solve this problem and others. This "start point" means something you can "see" from a problem to start solution. i got from you only solution, not how i can think this problem.

Comment: well, for starters, have you tried to prove $(G-H)\cup\{e\}$ subgroup $\rightarrow H=G,\{e\}$ directly, or assuming $H\neq G,\{e\}$ and derive $(G-H)\cup\{e\}$ is not a subgroup?

Comment: I said in my post what i tried.

Comment: @sticknycu Now you have seen the idea, I suggest to try your luck on the following statement: a group can never be the union of two proper subgroups.

Comment: @NickyHekster I think i maked it.

Comment: Let $G$ a group and $H_1, H_2$ proper subgroups with property $G = H_1 \cup H_2$. Let $x \in H_1, y \in H_2$. Hence $H_1, H_2$ are subgroups we have $x^{-1} \in H_1$ and $y^{-1} \in H_2$. We have $x \in H_1 = G - H_2$ and $y \in H_2$ and that means $xy \in G - H_2$. Hence $y \in H_2$ we get $xyy^{-1} \in G - H_2$. But $xyy^{-1} = x \in H_1$, contradiction :) It's ok? :)

Comment: beware, $g\in H_1$ doesn't mean $g\in G-H_2$, this would work only if $H_1\cap H_2=\emptyset$, but the idea is correct and notice that "$(G-H)\cup\{e\}$ is a subgroup if and only if $H$ is improper" is a consequence of the statement Nicky Hekster posted

Comment: If $g \in H_1$ that means $g \in (G-H_2) \cup \{ e \} $ ?

Comment: well no, because $e$ is not the only element two proper subgroups can share. You cannot derive $y\in G-H_2$ from $y\in H_1$, but you can assume such $y$ exists, that is, an $y\in H_1\wedge y\notin H_2$ (in no such $y$ exists, then $y\in H_1\rightarrow y\in H_2\rightarrow H_1\subseteq H_2$ and $G=H_1\cup H_2=H_2$, against the hypothesis of $H_1,H_2$ being proper)

Comment: I don't understand the last part..

Comment: when you look at the elements of $H_1$, they either belong to $H_2$ or to $G-H_2$, so either there is an element $x\in H_1$ which does not belong to $H_2$ or all the elements of $H_1$ are elements of $H_2$, so $H_1\subseteq H_2$, but then $H_1\cup H_2$ (which equals $G$ by hypothesis) would be equal to $H_2$ (if you unite a set with one of its subsets it doesn't change), and this would mean $G=H_2$, when we specifically asked $H_2$ to be proper subgroups

Comment: ok, thank you for your time

Comment: you'are welcome